# If X and Y are iid random variables and g is a measurable function on $(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^2})$, is $E[g(X,Y)]=E[g(Y,X)]$ correct?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, independence, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let X and Y be iid random variables. Let $g(\cdot,\cdot)$ be a measurable function on $(R^2, \mathcal{B}_{R^2})$, where $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^2}$ is the Borel sets on $\mathbb{R}^2$. If $\mathbb{E}g(X,Y)$ exists, is $\mathbb{E}g(X,Y)=\mathbb{E}g(Y,X)$ correct?

Comment: Yes, because $(X,Y)$ and $(Y,X)$ have the same distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathcal L$ be the law of $X$ (and also $Y$, by assumption). Then the law of the vector $(X,Y)$ is $\mathcal L\otimes \mathcal L$ (product of measures), which is the same as the law of $(Y,X)$, so $\mathbb Eg(X,Y) = \mathbb Eg(Y,X)$.